# Sobreposição de Divs com Scroll até ao topo

Tags: javascript, style

Preciso de fazer uma sobreposição de divs tal com esta, a parar o scroll no topo da página e vir a outra por cima.

http://jsfiddle.net/8b3ae5re/1/

Mas não estou a conseguir criar uma página a fazer isto. Alguém me pode ajudar??

Desde já obrigado :)

Comment: Sem código e sem mostrar o problema especifico que tem na página é complicado.

Comment: Olá Isac, desde já obrigado.

Simplesmente quero fazer uma página como a que está no link em cima, no canto inferior direito. 

No entanto crio um html com o css, script e htm e o resultado não é o pretendido.

Podes ajudar?

Comment: Nós aqui não fazemos páginas por ninguém, mas ajudamos qualquer pessoa com dificuldades relacionadas à programação. Se é o caso adiciona à pergunta a página que já tens feita e explica onde não está a funcionar como esperas.

Comment: Bem-vindo Pedro, visite esse post para ser bem sucedido em suas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: este também https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Comment: e esse também é importante https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: achei um exemplo e publiquei na resposta

Answer (score 0):

Coloque uma div fixa no topo e a div que vai sobrepor com z-index maior

**CSS**

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

h1,h2{
    color:#ccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 1;
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.div2{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <h1>Conteudo div1</h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
 <h2>Conteudo div2</h2>
</div>
```

Achei um [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/wQQEM/)

```js
$(function() {

    // Set up vars
    var _window = $(window),
        panels = $('.panel'),
        panelsY = [];

    // Cache position of each panel
    $.each(panels, function(i, el) {
        panelsY.push(panels.eq(i).offset().top);
    });

    // Bind our function to window scroll
    _window.bind('scroll', function() {
        updateWindow();
    });

    // Update the window
    function updateWindow() {
        var y = _window.scrollTop();

        // Loop through our panel positions
        for (i = 0, l = panels.length; i < l; i++) {
            /* 
                Firstly, we break if we're checking our last panel,
                otherwise we compare if he y position is in between
                two panels
            */
            if ((i === l - 1) || (y >= panelsY[i] && y <= panelsY[i+1])) {
                break;
            }
        };

        // Update classes
        panels.not(':eq(' + i + ')').removeClass('panel-fixed');
        panels.eq(i).addClass('panel-fixed');
    };

});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }

.panel {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
    z-index: 5;
    }
    .panel-fixed {
        z-index: 1;
        }
    .panel-inner {
        padding: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        }
        .panel-fixed .panel-inner {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            }

.panel-one {
    background-color: red;
    }

.panel-two {
    background-color: blue;
    }

.panel-three {
    background-color: green;
    }

/* Base */
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    font: 100%/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
    }

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-one">
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-two">
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-three">
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```